# How add query result to object in codeigniter and after to Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have problem make a object which i want to transfering to Angular.
My code is below:

```
class Pokayokes_model extends CI_Model {

public function get( $name = false, $number = false ) 
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('poke_yoke p'); 
            $this->db->join('rysunek r', 'r.nazwa_rys=p.nazwa_rys', 'left');
            $this->db->where('r.nazwa_rys',$name);

            $query = $this->db->get();



            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                echo $res1 = $row['nazwa_art'];
                echo $res2 = $row['kolory_art'];

                $start = 7;
                $end = 7 + $number;         


                for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
                {
                    $j = $i - 6;
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $res3 = $row['py_'.$j.''];
                }

               $qResults[] = $res1.','.$res2.','.$res3;
               echo "<pre>";
               var_dump($qResults);
               echo "</pre>";
              }
  return ?;
```

}

A know that I need use something like this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

but I don't know how make of this line `$row['py_'.$j.'']` object.
In database  I have columns like py_1, py_2, py_3, ... etc but not every time a need all of it. Sometimes I need only 3, sometime 10, so I need to generate dynamically.

---

15.08.15 edit:

I'm trying for the last 2 days make this code work, but it didn't.
I think this code is not right. 
I need to this part (below) make object but I don't know how?

```
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
  $j = $i - 6;
  $res3 = $row['py_'.$j.''];
}
```

Because I want use this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

I have one question more...
How I display this result form this loop? I need to add to array? What I need write next to result?
I want to output be like this at the end:

```
[
{"nazwa_art":"11_13_1532","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K","py_1":"Y","py_2":"Y","py_3":"M","py_4":"M","py_5":"M","py_6":"M"},
{"nazwa_art":"11_13_1512","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K","py_1":"Y","py_2":"Y","py_3":"M","py_4":"M","py_5":"x","py_6":"x"}
]
```

---

21.08.15 edit:

I made another modification of my code and it looks like this:

```
class Pokayokes_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get( $pokayokeName = false, $number = false ) 
    {           

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('poke_yoke p'); 
        $this->db->join('rysunek r', 'r.nazwa_rys=p.nazwa_rys', 'left');
        $this->db->where('r.nazwa_rys',$pokayokeName);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $res1 = $row['nazwa_art'];
            $res2 = $row['kolory_art'];

            $qResults = array();
            $qResults['nazwa_art'] = $res1;
            $qResults['kolory_art'] = $res2;


            $start = 7;
            $end = 7 + $number;         
            for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
            {
                $j = $i - 6;
                $res3 = $row['py_'.$j.''];
                $qResults['py_'.$j.''] = $res3;
            } 

        }

    echo json_encode($qResults);

    }
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
{"nazwa_art":"11_15_0492","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K,PBlue5575,PGreenYellow5576","py_1":"x","py_2":"PGreenYellow5576","py_3":"PGreenYellow5576","py_4":"PBlue5575","py_5":"PBlue5575" }
```

but should be 3 results and not only one.

And I don't know why in  Angular is null?

Comment: return the result to the controller and echo as json_encode() function then you can catch it in angular js

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
class Pokayokes_model extends CI_Model {

public function get( $name = false, $number = false ) 
{           
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('poke_yoke p'); 
     $this->db->join('rysunek r', 'r.nazwa_rys=p.nazwa_rys', 'left');
     $this->db->where('r.nazwa_rys',$name);

     $query = $this->db->get();

     foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $res1 = $row['nazwa_art'];
        $res2 = $row['kolory_art'];

        $start = 7;
        $end = 7 + $number;         
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
            $j = $i - 6;
            $res3 = $row['py_'.$j.''];
        }

         $qResults[] = $res1.','.$res2.','.$res3;
    }

    echo json_encode(['result'=>$qResults]);

}
}
```

Comment: This is not working :( I have error this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'".

Comment: ohh i missed to put quotes in array key. Answer updated